# Отличия свойства от переменной

Tags: javascript

В чем отличие свойства объекта от переменной глобального объекта?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> В JavaScript все глобальные переменные и функции являются свойствами
>   специального объекта, который называется «глобальный объект» (global
>   object). В браузере этот объект явно доступен под именем `window`.
>   Объект `window` одновременно является глобальным объектом и содержит ряд
>   свойств и методов для работы с окном браузера.

Присваивая или читая глобальную переменную, мы, фактически, работаем со свойствами `window`, например:

```
var a = 5; // объявление var создаёт свойство window.a
alert(window.a); // 5
```

Создать переменную можно и явным присваиванием в `window`:

```
window.a = 5;
alert(a); // 5
```

Соответственно, отличий особо нет. Ну, кроме того, что к переменной еще можно обратиться просто по имени. Ссылка для ознакомления: [Глобальный объект](https://learn.javascript.ru/global-object) Глобальные переменные на самом деле являются свойствами объекта `window` - значит это одно и то же.