# Почему в ООП функции и переменные именованы свойствами и методами?

Tags: ооп

Почему в ООП функции и переменные именованы свойствами и методами, ведь, не важно в каком стиле написан код, процедурном или объектно ориентированном, свойства и методы будут выполнять те же самые функции и иметь те же самые свойства как их не называй.

Comment: что за набор слов

Answer (score 1):

Метод и функция - это разные понятия - следовательно имеют свои определения, соответственно , отличия.

[Разница между методом и функцией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711189/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Различия ПП и ООП

http://artanovy.com/2011/03/procedurnoe-protiv-obyektno-orientirovannogo/

Пример из JS по поводу различий между переменными и свойствами:

[Отличия свойства от переменной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916226/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Comment: Спасибо за то, что не стали игнорировать вопрос новичка в ооп.

Comment: Не за что ) Удачи в изучении )

Answer (score 0):

Переменные и методы в Функциональном программировании и в Объектно-ориентированном программировании несут разные функции.

В объектно ориентированных языках программирования переменные называют **полями**.

**Отличия обычной переменной от поля:**

1. Само по себе поле не может существовать вне класса или структуры - это переменная в ООП.
2. Поля, использующиеся в классе имеют модификатор доступа только **private или protected**
3. Изначально к ним приписывается модификатор private, поэтому указывать его перед типом поля не обязательно.

**Пример (язык C#):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PoleQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
    class People
    {
        string Name; //Поле с модификатором private
        protected int Age; // Поле с модификатором protected
    }
}
```

Но также в ООП есть ещё один особый вид переменных. Он называется - **Свойство**.

**Свойство** - это гибкий механизм для чтения, записи или вычисления значения частного поля

**Отличия обычной переменной от свойства:**

1. Свойства позволяют классу предоставлять общий способ получения и задания значений, скрывая при этом код реализации или проверки.
2. В свойствах есть два аксессора доступа - get и set.

   **get** - это аксессор доступа, который предназначен только для возврата значений свойства

   **set** - это аксессор, который предназначен только для внесений новых значений в свойство.
3. Одна из основных парадигм ООП появилась в связи с появлением свойств - инкапсуляции.
   **Пример (Язык C#):**

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace PoleQuestion
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {


           }
       class People
       {
           public string Name { get; set; } // Укороченная запись свойства
           int a;
           public int Age // Полная(подробная) запись свойства
           {
               get
               {
                   if (a <= 0)
                       return 1;
                   return a;
               }

               set
               {
                   a = value;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

И последнее - это методы. Методы в функциональном программировании и в ООП представляют собой определённый набор кода, который срабатывает, когда мы вызываем этот метод. Здесь различий практически нет, поэтому можно считать **метод** и **функцию** одинаковыми вещами.

Надеюсь этот ответ был вам полезен в изучении объектно-ориентированного программирования.